# What does this smart Data mean on my hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

[image]

My hard drive is a bit slow. I forget which brand I bought.

I wonder what does it say?

Also things are slow when I run my computer on 4k resolution. Normal resolution seems to do fine.

Comment: I'd suggest you to consult SeaTools for the interpretation instead: https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drive is in a very bad shape.
If "Power-On Hours" is to be believed to be 97 hours, then this is a
new disk and should still be under warranty, to be replaced or returned.

The "Current Pending Sector Count" and the "Uncorrectable Sector Count"
are both 92, which means that there are 92 sectors that require remapping
to spare sectors, but that the disk firmware doesn't manage to salvage.
Both values are critical S.M.A.R.T. parameters, to be taken very seriously.

Normally 92 bad sectors are not a problem, as the disk surely has a
few thousand spare sectors that will replace the bad ones.
What is a problem is its inability to salvage these bad spots.

It is unknown how long the disk will keep on working before failure,
so keep complete backups of your data, to be safe.

Comment: Regardless of whether drive is really in a bad shape and/or whether definitions are correct, AFAIK the raw values are what you should look at / quote for your interpretation.

Comment: @TomYan: The raw values can be misleading, since some values are composed with sub-fields. For this post the raw value is `AC0` which is even worse at 2752. It's much safer to use a program that understands the raw values and their structure.

Comment: That doesn't make the Current values mean what you said, and why I suggested SeaTools to the OP.